# Transitions on IE10 do not work on two absolutely positioned elements (With example)

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, internet-explorer-10

Basically i have two divs absolutely positioned in the same spot, and slide through them with opacity controls.

Using modernizr i check for css transition support and rely on Jquery fades for Ie8 and Ie9, but Ie10 does have transitions so it doesnt fall back to that, and it plain doesnt work there.

The following example was tested on chrome and Ie10

http://jsfiddle.net/ycheG/

I would like to avoid heavy html/css changes on this structure, and the javascript fallback is decent enough if i didnt have to sniff for it.

### HTML

```
<div class="opaque"></div>
<div class="opaque green active"></div>

<button> Toggle</button>
enter code here
```

### CSS

```
.opaque {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  width:100px; 
  height:100px; 
  background-color:red; 
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
  opacity:0;
}

.opaque.green {
   background-color: green;
}

.opaque.active {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

### JS

```
$("button").on("click", function(){ 
  $(".opaque").toggleClass("active");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
```

this should work for ie10 , also you can read about Cross-browser